# Getting unique result in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

how can we get distinct result by using criteria in hibernate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=941669

Comment: One should rather consider to get distinct results by using a database query (e.g. SELECT DISTINCT(xyz) from X) instead of using Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY. Please note that Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY gets the unique results from the objects in memory (and not from the database), which might be costly for large result sets.

Answer (score 6):

A more flexible solution may be:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("property")));
```

Comment: You may want to avoid using Projection.distinct because it has the nasty unintended side affect of reducing the result set to only that one property.

Answer (score 1):

depends on your query/criteria.
if you provide a unique id you can call criteria.uniqueResult()
otherwise you call criteria.setMaxResults(1) and call criteria.uniqueResult()